# Wolfram Programming Cloud error Set::write: Tag Times in á l$$ $CellContext`materi is Protected

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why I get the error below with this code:

```
CloudDeploy[
 DynamicModule[{fimo = 0, háček = 0, kalota = 0, karabina = 0, 
   lak = False, lanko = False, očko = 0, rokajl = 0, šlupna = 0, 
   špuntík = 0, materiál = 0, práce = 0, cena = 0}, 
  Deploy[Style[
    Panel[Grid[
      Transpose[{{Style["Polymerové hmoty", Italic], "FIMO Soft", "", 
         Style["Komponenty", Italic], "Háček", "Kalota", "Karabina", 
         "Lak", "Lanko", "Očko", "Rokajl", "Šlupna", "Špuntík", "", 
         Style["Práce", Italic], "Práce", "", 
         Style["Cena za materiál", Bold, Larger], 
         Style["Cena za výrobek", Red, Bold, Larger]}, {"", 
         InputField[Dynamic[fimo], Number], "", "", 
         InputField[Dynamic[háček], Number], 
         InputField[Dynamic[kalota], Number], 
         InputField[Dynamic[karabina], Number], 
         Checkbox[Dynamic[lak]], Checkbox[Dynamic[lanko]], 
         InputField[Dynamic[očko], Number], 
         InputField[Dynamic[rokajl], Number], 
         InputField[Dynamic[šlupna], Number], 
         InputField[Dynamic[špuntík], Number], "", "", 
         InputField[Dynamic[práce], Number], "", 
         InputField[
          Dynamic[materiál = (50 fimo)/56 + 0.5 háček + 0.5 kalota + 
             10 karabina + 0.5 očko + 0.5 rokajl + 4 šlupna + 
             0.5 špuntík; 
           If[lak, materiál += (100 fimo)/(1/35 (10 56) 35), 
            materiál]; If[lanko, materiál++, materiál]; 
           materiál = Ceiling[materiál]], Enabled -> False], 
         InputField[Dynamic[materiál + práce], 
          Enabled -> False]}, {"", "g", "", "", "ks", "ks", "ks", "", 
         "", "ks", "ks", "ks", "ks", "", "", ",- Kč", "", ",- Kč", 
         ",- Kč"}}], Alignment -> Left]], 
    DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, 
        FieldSize -> {{5, 30}, {1, \[Infinity]}}}}]]], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Error:

```
Set::write: Tag Times in á l$$ $CellContext`materi is Protected.
```

I obtain this error only on deployed page. When I try to run the code inside the CloudDeploy function in Mathematica, there are no problems.

Brief overview:

This program is a simple interactive calculator of the price of FIMO jewels. It computes it from the amount of used FIMO and other jewel's components.

Thanks,

Zdenek

Comment: Please give a brief overview of what your code is doing? Or what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggests the variable `materiál` is not being interpreted correctly and is being split to `materi l` which is then being multiplied, hence the `Times` error.  Try replacing `materiál` with  `material` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps me a lot. That was a problem.